# How to change property after mouse release

Tags: python, scripting

I have a custom property of the type bpy.props.FloatProperty , that has a update=update_function .
then I have that mapped to a row.prop() with slider=True.
Now for better and predictable user experience I want that custom float property to go back to 0,when the mouse releases the click.Since a release on the slider means that the user is no longer updating the function.

I've tried to do this in the update function,while this worked...somehow,the thing was that it was resetting the value with each update iteration so this was creating a big lag in performance.
Is it doable?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly no. Blender API can track if a mouse button is released or not...but ,won't allow you to fiddle with the release state of a UI button or slider.